# Partial Multiple File Naming in Ubuntu

Tags: unix, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-12.04

I want to rename files from:

my.fi.name.123.txt, my.fi.name.124.txt, my.fi.name.125.txt etc2 into

new.file.link.123.txt, new.file.link.124.txt .. etc2.

What's the best command to do this in ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
for file in my*; do mv ${file} "${file/my.fi.name/new.file.link}"; done
```

#### Test:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  0 Feb 25 19:33 my.fi.name.125.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  0 Feb 25 19:33 my.fi.name.124.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  0 Feb 25 19:33 my.fi.name.123.txt
```

```
$ for file in my*; do mv ${file} "${file/my.fi.name/new.file.link}"; done
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  0 Feb 25 19:33 new.file.link.125.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  0 Feb 25 19:33 new.file.link.124.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jaypalsingh  staff  0 Feb 25 19:33 new.file.link.123.txt
```